# JTable column uneditable after adding JComboBox to a cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I have a JTable component with 2 columns, for the second column iwant to add a JComboBox for only one cell, following oracle documentation i've created my own cell editor, and added the JComboBox but after that all of the other cells from the column became uneditable.
Here is an example:

[Before adding the JComboBox:](http://makeagif.com/c0Fps9)

After adding the JComboBox, i could not edit the other cells

[After adding the JComboBox:](http://makeagif.com/bza6-6)

My Code:

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(textosTabela, stubColumnNames);
tabela.setModel(model);
tabela.setBorder(new LineBorder(Color.black));
tabela.setGridColor(Color.black);
tabela.setShowGrid(true);
tabela.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(290, 132));
tabela.setRowHeight(22);
tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(0).setPreferredWidth(160);
tabela.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
TableColumn tm = tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(0);
tm.setCellRenderer(new ColorColumnRenderer(Color.lightGray));
TableColumn comboCol1 = tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(valoresComboBox);
comboBox.setSelectedIndex(0);
comboCol1.setCellEditor(new ComboBoxEditor(1,3,comboBox));
```

CellEditor Code:

```
public class ComboBoxEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

    private String[] values;
    private String selectedValue;
    private int column = -1;
    private int row = -1;

    public ComboBoxEditor(JComboBox values) {
        super(values);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public ComboBoxEditor(int column, int row, JComboBox values) {
        super(values);
        this.column = column;
        this.row = row;

    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Component c = table.getEditorComponent();
        if(column == this.column && row == this.row) {
            return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
        }

        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that returns a different combobo box by row. If there is no combo box for the row then the default editor is used:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class TableComboBoxByRow extends JPanel
{
    List<String[]> editorData = new ArrayList<String[]>(3);

    public TableComboBoxByRow()
    {
        setLayout( new BorderLayout() );

        // Create the editorData to be used for each row

        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Red", "Blue", "Green" } );
        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Circle", "Square", "Triangle" } );
        editorData.add( new String[]{ "Apple", "Orange", "Banana" } );

        //  Create the table with default data

        Object[][] data =
        {
            {"Color", "Red"},
            {"Shape", "Square"},
            {"Fruit", "Banana"},
            {"Plain", "Text"}
        };
        String[] columnNames = {"Type","Value"};

        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data, columnNames);
        JTable table = new JTable(model)
        {
            //  Determine editor to be used by row
            public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column)
            {
                int modelColumn = convertColumnIndexToModel( column );

                if (modelColumn == 1 && row < 3)
                {
                    JComboBox<String> comboBox1 = new JComboBox<String>( editorData.get(row));
                    return new DefaultCellEditor( comboBox1 );
                }
                else
                    return super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        };

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
        add( scrollPane );
//      table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellRenderer(new ComboBoxRenderer2() );
    }
    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Table Combo Box by Row");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( new TableComboBoxByRow() );
        frame.setSize(200, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The key is overriding the `getCellEditor(...)` method instead of creating a custom renderer.

Comment: @MadProgrammer,  I changed my answer, so people might not know what you are referring to :) Anyway, isn't the point of a view to allow you to have different views of the data? Wouldn't edibility be considered a different view?

Comment: But now, if I add the model to another instance of `JTable`, we have different behaviour which is inconsistent with the rules of the data.  In this, the model is acting (slightly) as the controller ... ah Swing and it's "kind of" MVC

Comment: It's also one of the issues I have with overriding `prepareRenderer`, you're now stuck with a particular implementation of `JTable` which may become inflexible in the future. Maybe taking the time to actually design a "controller" `interface` would be a better solution in the long run, something which is indepedent of the instance of `JTable` :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer, `But now, if I add the model to another instance of JTable, we we have different behaviour` - Is that not reasonable? For example the model has basic edibility. But then you have a supervisor who can login and have additional update abilities. Would you not handle this through the view so you can toggle it on/off and you don't have to recreate the model?

Comment: But I'd still think it's not the views responsibility to make that decision. Do a need a new table for each new rule that comes up? If really nessacery, I might create a wrapper model which controls the rules. The view should be responsible for displaying the data, not making business decisions.

Comment: This is kind of where Swings MVC begins to fall down, thus is where the controller would be used to change get state of the view, which is been done by the model in this case :P

Comment: I tell you what, make it do the decisions which prepareCellRenderer are making come from a model/controller and I'll agree with you ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, Well, I can't say that I understand the true MVC design. I've only ever played with the Swing implementation. I'm not saying a controller isn't the proper solution. However I don't know how to write a controller (and I'm guessing people who ask question. It seems that you are suggesting to me that we should NEVER override a method of the View that is a convenience method to access the Model method of the same name?

Comment: Are you questioning the solution currently posted here? Does it not address the OPs question? The model will say the cell is editable. Overriding the `getCellEditor()` method will just choose the editor to be used when editing the cell. Is that not a function of the View?

Comment: I guess one of my "bug bears" is I've spent 6 years undoing and redesigning `JTable` implementations that my predecessor kept making (doing things like overriding `preapreRenderer` etc), when some time spent actually thinking about how they wanted to modify the table might have been achieved through a more configurable manner.  Again, it just comes down to, how many tables do I really need?

Comment: No, I'm questioning the choice.  Why at the base, it's probably what needs to be done, it's not a reusable solution and is only going to encourage more bad decisions - IMHO

Comment: @MadProgrammer,  I admit I am sometimes (often?) guilty of simplified answers. As someone who learned Swing on his own I know I had to learn it in steps. When I started I would be overwhelmed by the solution you posted (I still am). I believe most people who ask question are learning by themselves and are not working as part of a large team otherwise they would ask team members for help. Sometime we just want to get something work and then learn from our mistakes as we gain knowledge. Most solutions I post I try to make reusable, but sometimes I fail.

Comment: Maybe I'm just "expecting" more then is actually required for the question, but I just get a little "frustrated" when the answer is to just override the basic implementation, especially something so complex as jtable. I don't think the answer is "wrong", but just missed the discussion of "where to go from here", but again, maybe I'm just expecting more then is really required ;)

Answer (score 2):

The `TableModel` should dictate which cells are editable or not, by default, `DefaultTableModel` makes all cell's editable.

In your `TableCellEditor`, you have...

```
if (column == this.column && row == this.row) {
    return super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);
}
```

Which seems to be making the decisions for the editor, which the model should be, for example

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(textosTabela, stubColumnNames) {
    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
        return row == 3 && column == 1;
    }
};
```

And the just use the `DefaltCellEditor` to wrap your `JComboBox`

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(valoresComboBox);
DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(comboBox);

TableColumn comboCol1 = tabela.getColumnModel().getColumn(1);
```

I might point out that, generally speaking, `JTable` isn't really good as acting as a property sheet editor, where the value of a cell is different for each row

## PropertySheetEditor

Reusability and configurability would be my two major concerns with any type of implementation.  It's now really the tables responsibility to make decisions about how things should be rendered or edited, this is why with have renderers and editors.  What we need is some way to provide a configurable element into the API which can make the decisions we need and leave the table to do the job it's currently doing.

Since the `JTable` isn't really designed to handle multiple types of data for a specific column, along with different renderers and editors, we need to provide that functionality.

### A Property

Let's start with the key element, the property.  A property has three basic elements, a name, value and type.

```
public interface Property<T> {
    public String getName();
    public T getValue();
    public Class<T> getType();
    public void setValue(T value);
}
```

I did think about making another `interface` for mutable properties, but you could just as easily add a `readOnly` property to this interface if that's required.

And because I'm lazy...

```
public class DefaultProperty<T> implements Property<T> {

    private final String name;
    private T value;
    private final Class<T> type;

    public DefaultProperty(String name, T value, Class<T> type) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.type = type;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public T getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public Class<T> getType() {
        return type;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(T value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

}
```

### The Model

Now, we need model which can manage our `Property`'s and the contract with the `JTable`...

```
public interface PropertySheetModel extends TableModel {        
    public Property getPropertyAt(int row);
}
```

And because I'm lazy...

```
public class DefaultPropertySheeModel extends AbstractTableModel implements PropertySheetModel {

    private List<Property> properties;

    public DefaultPropertySheeModel(List<Property> properties) {
        this.properties = new ArrayList<>(properties);
    }

    @Override
    public int getRowCount() {
        return getProperties().size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2; // Key/value
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Property p = getPropertyAt(rowIndex);
        Object value = null;
        switch (columnIndex) {
            case 0:
                value = p.getName();
                break;
            case 1:
                value = p.getValue();
                break;
        }
        return value;
    }

    @Override
    public void setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        Property p = getPropertyAt(rowIndex);
        p.setValue(aValue);
        fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex);
    }

    @Override
    public Property getPropertyAt(int row) {
        return getProperties().get(row);
    }

    protected List<Property> getProperties() {
        return properties;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCellEditable(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        return columnIndex != 0;
    }

}
```

It wouldn't take much to make a dynamic model, where you could add/remove `Property`'s, it's just beyond the scope of this answer ;)

### A Delegate

Okay, now we need something to start making more complex decisions for us. This is where the delegate comes in, we can use it to answer some of the questions that we don't really want to answer ourselves

```
public interface PropertySheetDelegate {

    public TableCellEditor getCellEditorFor(Property property);

    public void setCellEditorFor(Property property, TableCellEditor editor);
    public void setCellEditorFor(Class type, TableCellEditor editor);

    public TableCellRenderer getCellRendererFor(Property property);
    public void setCellRendererFor(Property property, TableCellRenderer editor);
    public void setCellRendererFor(Class type, TableCellRenderer editor);

}
```

And because I'm lazy...

```
public class DefaultPropertySheetDelegate implements PropertySheetDelegate {

    private Map<Property, TableCellEditor> propertyEditors;
    private Map<Class, TableCellEditor> typeEditors;

    private Map<Property, TableCellRenderer> propertyRenderers;
    private Map<Class, TableCellRenderer> typeRenderers;

    public DefaultPropertySheetDelegate() {
        propertyEditors = new HashMap<>(25);
        typeEditors = new HashMap<>(25);
        propertyRenderers = new HashMap<>(25);
        typeRenderers = new HashMap<>(25);

        JTextField field = new JTextField();
        field.setBorder(null);

        DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(field);
        editor.setClickCountToStart(1);
        setCellEditorFor(String.class, editor);
    }

    @Override
    public TableCellEditor getCellEditorFor(Property property) {
        TableCellEditor editor = propertyEditors.get(property);
        if (editor == null) {
            editor = typeEditors.get(property.getType());
        }
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    public void setCellEditorFor(Property property, TableCellEditor editor) {
        propertyEditors.put(property, editor);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCellEditorFor(Class type, TableCellEditor editor) {
        typeEditors.put(type, editor);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCellRendererFor(Class type, TableCellRenderer renderer) {
        typeRenderers.put(type, renderer);
    }

    @Override
    public void setCellRendererFor(Property property, TableCellRenderer renderer) {
        propertyRenderers.put(property, renderer);
    }

    @Override
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRendererFor(Property property) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = propertyRenderers.get(property);
        if (renderer == null) {
            renderer = typeRenderers.get(property.getType());
        }
        return renderer;
    }

}
```

Now, this implementation simply deals with the `TableCellEditor`, realistically, you should probably also have it deal with the renderers as well.

## The View...

And finally, we need some way to show it, this is a customised `JTable` (obviously), which uses the `PropertySheetDelegate` and `PropertySheetModel` to present the data been managed...

```
public class PropertySheet extends JTable {

    private PropertySheetDelegate propertySheetDelegate;

    public PropertySheet(PropertySheetDelegate controller, PropertySheetModel model) {
        super(model);
        setDelegate(controller);
    }

    public PropertySheet() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void setModel(TableModel dataModel) {
        if (dataModel instanceof PropertySheetModel || dataModel == null) {
            super.setModel(dataModel);
        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported PropertySheetModel " + dataModel.getClass().getName());
        }
    }

    public PropertySheetDelegate getPropertySheetDelegate() {
        return propertySheetDelegate;
    }

    public void setDelegate(PropertySheetDelegate value) {
        if (propertySheetDelegate != value) {
            PropertySheetDelegate old = propertySheetDelegate;
            this.propertySheetDelegate = value;
            firePropertyChange("propertySheetController", old, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public TableCellEditor getCellEditor(int row, int column) {
        TableCellEditor editor = null;
        // Assumes that only the values can be modified
        if (column == 1) {
            PropertySheetDelegate delegate = getPropertySheetDelegate();
            if (delegate != null) {
                PropertySheetModel model = (PropertySheetModel) getModel();
                Property property = model.getPropertyAt(row);
                editor = delegate.getCellEditorFor(property);

                System.out.println("Editor for " + property + " = " + editor);

                if (editor == null) {
                    editor = getDefaultEditor(property.getType());
                    System.out.println("Default Editor for " + property.getType() + " = " + editor);
                }
            } else {
                editor = super.getCellEditor(row, column);
            }
        }
        return editor;
    }

    @Override
    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = null;
        if (column == 1) {
            PropertySheetDelegate delegate = getPropertySheetDelegate();
            if (delegate != null) {
                PropertySheetModel model = (PropertySheetModel) getModel();
                Property property = model.getPropertyAt(row);
                renderer = delegate.getCellRendererFor(property);
                if (renderer == null) {
                    renderer = getDefaultRenderer(property.getType());
                }
            } else {
                renderer = super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
            }
        } else {
            renderer = super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
        }
        return renderer;
    }

}
```

## The plumbing

And finally, some what to make it work...

```
List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>(25);
properties.add(new DefaultProperty<>("Name", null, String.class));
properties.add(new DefaultProperty<>("Description", null, String.class));
properties.add(new DefaultProperty<>("Quanity", null, Integer.class));
properties.add(new DefaultProperty<>("Warrenty", null, Integer.class));
properties.add(new DefaultProperty<>("Returns", null, Boolean.class));

// This is our custom editor
DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
PropertySheetDelegate controller = new DefaultPropertySheetDelegate();
controller.setCellEditorFor(properties.get(2), editor);

PropertySheetModel model = new DefaultPropertySheeModel(properties);
PropertySheet propertySheet = new PropertySheet(controller, model);

setLayout(new BorderLayout());
add(new JScrollPane(propertySheet));
```

Comment: Doing what you said make all my cells becoming a JComboBox, what i want is that only the fourth cell become a JComboBox and the other keeps the default text editor.

Comment: But that's what I said at the end, JTable is designed do that each column contains the same type of data, is rendered and edited in the same way. Know, you need to know, in advance, the type of data the cell is suppose to have, the map that to a editor

Comment: So how do i in the DefaultCellEditor return the "TextEditor Mode" to the cells i want? Like in the DefaultCellEditor i return super.getTableCellEditorComponent and on the else i return null, what should i return instead of null?

Comment: I'd actually write a custom implementation of JTable, which took a custom model and additional controller which could make these decisions, do, when you change your mind or need to add/remove values, it rooks be easier to do. Not at a PC right now :P

Comment: I've made and adaptation on the code posted by camickr, i have override the getCellEditor during the creation of my JTable and using the if i could successfully selected only the cells i want.

Comment: Since you posted a more complete solution I thought I'd let people  know it doesn't work for other properties like Integer, Boolean etc. The JTable default editors need to know the Class of the cell being edited so the editor can create an instance of that Class when editing is finished. Also, the renderer for the 2nd column should reflect the Class of the cell. I edited your answer to include my simple solution. Feel free to use/modify/delete the code and comment :)

Comment: Yes, I didn't expand on adding default editors for everything (other the String, been lazy). Two solutions, 1: add it to the delegate; 2: Have the table model return the "Property"'s "type" with the PropertySheetModel. Had a 3 year old who wanted to go to the park ;)

Comment: I added the Boolean and Integer editors to the controller and get a ClassCastException. I think the problem is with the `getColumnClass()` method. AFAIK the default editors invoke this method so they can create and save a proper instance of the object to the TableModel. The getColumnClass() method of the TableModel doesn't have access to the row so it can't return the Class of the object, which is why I overrode the getColumnClass() method of the JTable.

Comment: @camickr  I've updated the basic implementation to support cell renderer's directly in the delegate.  The `PropertySheet` will delegate off to the `JTable` where on doesn't exist.  I've also update the editor selection process to delegate to the `defaultEditor` for the given class.  Thought about using `getColumnClass` but decided against it as I was already modifying the editor selection process anyway :P

Comment: Yes, default renderer/editor support is nice. I still have a problem. Instead of cluttering your answer I posted a new answer with my concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Using your new updates makes it easier to use the default renderers and editors.

However, in `JTable`, the `GenericEditor` uses the `getColumnClass()` method to convert the String entered into the text field into the proper Class so the value can be saved to the TableModel.

Your TableModel is using the default getColumnClass() implementation, so all values are considered Objects and are simply stored as a String.

You can verify this by clicking on the "Class of Selected Row" before and after editing the Integer or Double values. (The ComboBoxEditor and the BooleanEditor doesn't have a problem because they implement their own getCellEditorValue() method to return the proper value.)

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class PropertyTest extends JPanel
{
    public PropertyTest()
    {
        List<Property> properties = new ArrayList<>(25);
        properties.add(new DefaultProperty<>("String", "String", String.class));
        properties.add(new DefaultProperty<>("Integer Combo", new Integer(2), Integer.class));
        properties.add(new DefaultProperty<>("Boolean", Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.class));
        properties.add(new DefaultProperty<>("Integer", new Integer(1), Integer.class));
        properties.add(new DefaultProperty<>("Double", new Double(1.25), Double.class));

        // This is our custom editor
        DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JComboBox(new Integer[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}));
        PropertySheetDelegate delegate = new DefaultPropertySheetDelegate();
        delegate.setCellEditorFor(properties.get(1), editor);


        PropertySheetModel model = new DefaultPropertySheetModel(properties);
        final PropertySheet propertySheet = new PropertySheet(delegate, model);

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(new JScrollPane(propertySheet));

        JButton button = new JButton("Class of Selected Row");
        add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        button.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                int row = propertySheet.getSelectedRow();
                System.out.println(propertySheet.getValueAt(row, 1).getClass() );
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("PropertyTest");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new PropertyTest());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I think you need to override the `getColumnClass()` method of the `JTable` because it has access to the row being edited and the `TableModel` doesn't.

Here is the code I added to the PropertySheet class:

```
@Override
public Class getColumnClass(int column)
{
    int row = getSelectedRow();

    if (row == -1) return super.getColumnClass( column );

    PropertySheetDelegate controller = getPropertySheetDelegate();

    if (controller == null || column == 0)
    {
        return super.getColumnClass( column );
    }
    else
    {
        PropertySheetModel model = (PropertySheetModel) getModel();
        Property property = model.getPropertyAt(row);
        return property.getType();
    }
}
```

Although I'm sure you will find a better way to implement it :)

Comment: Haven't tested it, but I'd be worried about overriding getColumnClass and "assume" the row, but that's just me ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer, that's why I suggested you would come up with a better solution. The problem with the current code is that the default editors don't work. You can enter alphabetic characters in an Integer field. So that basically invalidates the whole concept of a "property editor". Given the current design of JTable the API does not support the concept of a `getColumnClassForCell(...)`, so you either need to rewrite the entire JTable UI, provide all custom editors,  or do something like I have proposed. I don't need a solution, I was just pointing out the way the default editors work.

Comment: Yep, a fully fledged solution would have "proper" default editors/renders preconfigured, I'm just to lazy to put them in ;). Doesn't the default editor for numbers use a JFormattedTextField? At least you'd get post validation :P

Comment: @MadProgrammer, no, it just uses a JTextField.